# Tisha b Av calendar confusion

Tags: calendar, tisha-bav

I don’t understand the calendar this holiday:

- iOS says today is 10 Av
- hebcal.com says 10 Av as well

but:

- google says Tisha b Av is today
- chabad.org says Tisha b Av is today (https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144575/jewish/What-Is-Tisha-BAv.htm)

but:

- main page of chabad.org says the date today is 10
  Av

What’s the deal? How did 9 Av end up on 10 Av?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This year the ninth day of the month of Av fell on Shabbat. Since fasting on Shabbat is forbidden, the *holiday* of Tisha b'av (which literally translates as "the Ninth of Av", hence the confusion) was pushed back to the following day, and is observed on the *Tenth* of Av on the calendar, as required by the relevant halacha.

This excerpt from  [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tisha_BeAv) provides the relevant info, citing the sources I've copied below:

> **When Tisha BeAv falls out on Shabbat or Sunday**
>
> **Delaying The Fast**
>
> 1. If Tisha B'av falls out on Shabbat, it is pushed off until Sunday and everything that would be forbidden on Tisha B'av is permitted on
>      Shabbat. [73] According to Ashkenazim, some hold that relations are
>      forbidden on Shabbat which is Tisha B'av unless it is her tevilah
>      night.[74] On the other hand, according to Sepharadim, relations are
>      permitted on Shabbat.[75]
> 2. If Tisha B'av falls out on Shabbat and is pushed off to Sunday, one may eat meat or drink wine on Monday day and not Sunday night. [76]
>      According to some poskim, one may even eat meat on Sunday night. [77]
> 3. One may, get a haircut or do laundry immediately on Sunday night. [78]
> 4. If Tisha BeAv falls out on Shabbat and is pushed off until Sunday, according to Sephardim, a pregnant woman or woman who is nursing may
>      eat on the fast day. Nonetheless, they should not eat for
>      pleasure.[79]
> 5. If Tisha Beav falls out on Shabbat and is pushed off to Sunday then there is a dispute among the poskim as to whether or not a boy who
>      becomes Bar Mitzvah on the 10th of Av is required to fast.[80]
>
> **Havdala on Motzaei Shabbat**
>
> 1. If Tisha BeAv falls out on Shabbat and is pushed off to Sunday, the bracha of Boreh Meorei HaEsh upon a fire is made on Motzei Shabbat
>      before the reading of Eicha (while Boreh Mineh/Isbeh/Atzeh Besamim is
>      omitted[81]), however, the bracha of Havdalah on a cup of wine is
>      delayed until after Tisha BeAv, Sunday night. [82] An adult who is
>      exempt from fasting should recite Havdalah on Motzei Shabbat before
>      eating.[83] One may fulfill his/her obligation to recite Havdalah even
>      through someone who is permitted to eat on Tisha BeAv.[84]
> 2. If one needs to eat on Tisha B'av that falls out on Sunday must recite Havdalah beforehand but they should wait until they need to eat
>      to recite Havdalah and not say it immediately Saturday night unless
>      they need to eat then.[85]

Shulchan Aruch O.C. 554:19, Kaf HaChaim 554:86, Yalkut Yosef 556:1